# MySQL returning wrong values

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm trying to query the current balance, however it seem to show the right balance at the end but the overall not correct. So basically the calculations is that

IF status equal to 'wrong'

balance = balance - 100

ELSE

balance = balance + (odds*100)

END

Below you see my output from my current query:

```
Odds    Status      Date                    balance
1.70  | wrong   |   2015-02-08 13:22:17 |   205
3.05  | correct |   2015-02-08 20:27:44 |   305
2.20  | correct |   2015-02-09 15:45:27 |   425
```

From my calculations the balance should be

```
-100
205
425
```

So why is it not showing this?

```
SET @balance = 0;
SELECT odds.meta_value AS odds, stat.meta_value AS stats, posts.post_date as postdate, 
        CASE WHEN stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
        THEN @balance := @balance -100
        ELSE @balance := @balance + (odds.meta_value * 100) 
        END as balance
        FROM  wp_t3a673_posts posts
        LEFT JOIN  wp_t3a673_postmeta stat ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
        AND stat.meta_key =  'status'
        LEFT JOIN  wp_t3a673_postmeta odds ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
        AND odds.meta_key =  'odds'
        LEFT JOIN  wp_t3a673_term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
        LEFT JOIN  wp_t3a673_term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE (
        stat.meta_value =  'correct'
        OR stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
        )
        AND posts.post_status =  'publish'
        AND t.taxonomy =  'category'
        AND (
        t.term_id =4
        OR t.term_id =5
        OR t.term_id =6
        )
ORDER BY posts.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had a close look at your code, but consider this before using variables in the way you do (From the MySQL documentation):

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> SET @a = @a + 1;
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

You can find more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: But would this fix the error where it calculates wrong? And i'm not sure exactly what you want me to change?

Comment: Looking closer, it seems the way you use the variables for summing is the "good" way. The joins do however leave plenty of room for duplicated values, but it's hard to tell without a data set. I would have made a query to list all data to see if anything is added more than once.

Comment: I'm using the more or less same query elsewhere and it counts correct it is just strange that it provide the right result in the end 425 but are not showing the -100 at the beginning

Comment: If you post a fiddle with example data (for example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/) it will be much easier to help you with this,